# Flutter: A way to append incoming data to ListView instead of rebuilding entire thing?

Tags: flutter

Summary: Planning to show readonly data array in a ListView widget.  Data comes in using a Provider.  Is it possible to not rebuild the entire ListView every time, and just append a new Tile to it?

Details: The ListView data set coming in is similar to log entries--it's static and only the last item is coming in.  Rebuilding the entire ListView every time seems a bit wasteful.  Is it possible to have it in such a way that it would append new Tile widgets on incoming data instead?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: *"Is it possible to have it in such a way that it would append new Tile widgets on incoming data instead?"* - no, there is no such way

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some sample code or your code. For now from this question I'll suggest you to take a look on `AnimatedList`.